# Javascript: Create array out array of objects with certain value using reduce / map etc

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create an array of objects from an array of objects, this is the data:

```
// Input:
const shippingMethodOptions = [{
  id: 1,
  carrier_token: 'fedex',
  carrier_name: 'Fedex',
  weight: 1,
  price: 3
}, {
  id: 2,
  carrier_token: 'fedex',
  carrier_name: 'Fedex',
  weight: 2,
  price: 6
}, {
  id: 3,
  carrier_token: 'fedex',
  carrier_name: 'Fedex',
  weight: 6,
  price: 9
}, {
  id: 4,
  carrier_token: 'usps',
  carrier_name: 'Usps',
  weight: 6,
  price: 9
}, {
  id: 5,
  carrier_token: 'delaware',
  carrier_name: 'Delaware',
  weight: 5,
  price: 10
}]
```

As you can see the data has `carrier_token` and `carrier_name`, what I want is to create an output array with the unique `carriers` like so:

```
// Output:
const carriers = [{
  carrier_token: 'fedex',
  carrier_name: 'Fedex'
}, {
  carrier_token: 'usps',
  carrier_name: 'USPS'
}, {
  carrier_token: 'delaware',
  carrier_name: 'Delaware'
}]
```

What I have tried is building it with a for loop, however I would love to know if this is possible in a more clean way (reduce?)

This is my current solution so far (but again, I would love to know if it's possible to make it cleaner with Reduce etc.)

```
const getCarriers = options => {
  const carriers = []

  options.forEach(({ carrier_token, carrier_name }) => {
    const foundIndex = _.findIndex(carriers, carrier => carrier.carrier_token === carrier_token)

    if (foundIndex !== -1) {
      return
    }

    carriers.push({
      carrier_token,
      carrier_name
    })
  })

  return carriers
}

const carriers = getCarriers(shippingMethodOptions)
```

Comment: @AndrewLi Sorry for that, I tried it with a for loop, but I want to know if it's possible using reduce / map etc.

Comment: Could you include your attempt in the post?

Comment: @AndrewLi Yep, done

Comment: @AndrewLi I don't think it's very fair to downvote an answer when it correctly answers the question. Based on your comments on my answer, even if my answer had been correct you would have downvoted. I also do explain my code very thoroughly, but I start with a code dump on simple questions like this and then edit the answer so that I have a chance of actually being seen before everyone else code-dumps and gets upvoted and/or accepted.

Comment: @Clonkex I don't think it's fair to encourage bad behavior on SO. Since the OP hadn't shown their effort *then*, it could have sent the message to other posters that asking for someone to write code for them was okay. Had your answer been *correct* and had explanation off the bat, I would have upvoted.

Comment: @AndrewLi Well... ok, but A) The OP still hasn't shown any effort to solve the question they asked themselves. All they've done is shown that they did a different thing, which means they're still asking for us to write their code for them. B) Phil did exactly what I did, and posted a code dump while progressively editing more and more to add an explanation. To be clear, I do definitely agree with you, but.... -sigh- honestly I can't argue, my answer was too easy for the question to have been good, you were right to downvote. I just love the easy questions because getting rep is so _**hard**_.

Comment: @Clonkex I meant 'someone to write code for them' as in "plzsendtehcodez". If someone shows what they've tried, then writing code for them is exactly what SO is for. Anyways, target good questions (though the lack thereof nowadays is what makes getting rep so hard and what makes people like me micromanage every answer I come across) and make them high quality with explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a pretty straight-forward *reduce* job.

What you'll need is a way to keep track of existing carriers. I recommend using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and storing keys made from the token and name, for example in a string like `"<token>:<name>"`.

```js
const shippingMethodOptions = [{"id":1,"carrier_token":"fedex","carrier_name":"Fedex","weight":1,"price":3},{"id":2,"carrier_token":"fedex","carrier_name":"Fedex","weight":2,"price":6},{"id":3,"carrier_token":"fedex","carrier_name":"Fedex","weight":6,"price":9},{"id":4,"carrier_token":"usps","carrier_name":"Usps","weight":6,"price":9},{"id":5,"carrier_token":"delaware","carrier_name":"Delaware","weight":5,"price":10}]

const carriers = shippingMethodOptions.reduce(function(arr, smo) {
  let key = `${smo.carrier_token}:${smo.carrier_name}`
  return this.has(key) ? arr : this.add(key) && arr.concat({
    carrier_token: smo.carrier_token,
    carrier_name: smo.carrier_name
  });
}.bind(new Set()), [])

console.info(carriers)
```

I'm binding the `Set` to the `reduce` callback so it can be used via the `this` keyword however you could just as easily create it outside the callback scope and store it in a variable, eg

```
const keys = new Set()
```

Comment: I had a pretty similar answer going. +1

Comment: Wow, the bind thing, awesome never knew this was possible. Thanks alot!

Comment: @randomKek it's unfortunate that `reduce` doesn't offer a built-in `thisArg` like `map` and `forEach` do

Comment: Damn. I think I'm a good JS programmer until I see this and realise I have zero idea what's going on. This kind of coding is so hard to read IMO.

Comment: @Phil I'm using babel, es6 but your exact code returns an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined` do you have an idea?

Comment: @randomKek no idea. Works in my browser in the snippet above. You're not using an arrow function are you? Maybe try creating the `Set` outside the callback scope (as shown at the bottom of my answer)

Comment: @Clonkex it's probably the boolean short-circuit evaluation. I could have been more verbose

Comment: @Clonkex Take it step by step. Lots of it is just condensed for brevity, such as the `&&` short circuiting. Once you understand how `reduce` works, it should make a bit more sense.

Comment: @Phil That's part of it. I'm struggling to work out what that actually does. Wouldn't `this.add(key) && arr.concat(etc)` make the function return true or false?

Comment: @Clonkex nope ~ [*"Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns `expr2`"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description)

Comment: @AndrewLi I do have some idea how `reduce` works since I wrote my own to figure it out (https://jsfiddle.net/9618or70/1/), but I don't understand how short circuiting applies here and I thought `bind` was specific to jQuery... looks like I have some painful learning to get through :/

Comment: @Clonkex for reference ~ [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: 0.o **OH**. I was feeling way, _way_ out of my depth next to you pros a second ago (even a bit depressed at how confused I was), but suddenly something clicked and I understood `bind`, the way `&&` actually works (kind of a "duh" moment) and the short circuiting all at once. So the `&&` is just a way to do two things in the "else" of the ternary and still return the `concat`'d array? Clever! I still detest the `${smo.carrier_token}` syntax though, so gross and unintuitive. I'm so happy that I understood it right now btw ;)

Comment: @Clonkex string template literals are one of my favourite recent JS additions. Don't know how we made it this far without them

Comment: With quick typing of quotation marks and plus signs :P

Answer (score 3):

I'd consider using `.reduce()` with a `Map()`, where the map entries have keys based on `${carrier_token}:${carrier_name}` and values in the required object format. Then use `Array.from()` on the `.values()` of the map.

```js
const shippingMethodOptions = [{"id":1,"carrier_token":"fedex","carrier_name":"Fedex","weight":1,"price":3},{"id":2,"carrier_token":"fedex","carrier_name":"Fedex","weight":2,"price":6},{"id":3,"carrier_token":"fedex","carrier_name":"Fedex","weight":6,"price":9},{"id":4,"carrier_token":"usps","carrier_name":"Usps","weight":6,"price":9},{"id":5,"carrier_token":"delaware","carrier_name":"Delaware","weight":5,"price":10}]

const carriers = Array.from(
  shippingMethodOptions.reduce((map, {carrier_token, carrier_name}) => {
    const key = `${carrier_token}:${carrier_name}`
    if (!map.has(key)) map.set(key, { carrier_token, carrier_name })
    return map
  }, new Map()).values()
)

console.log(carriers)
```

Or if just the `carrier_token` is enough for uniqueness you can simplify it:

```js
const shippingMethodOptions = [{"id":1,"carrier_token":"fedex","carrier_name":"Fedex","weight":1,"price":3},{"id":2,"carrier_token":"fedex","carrier_name":"Fedex","weight":2,"price":6},{"id":3,"carrier_token":"fedex","carrier_name":"Fedex","weight":6,"price":9},{"id":4,"carrier_token":"usps","carrier_name":"Usps","weight":6,"price":9},{"id":5,"carrier_token":"delaware","carrier_name":"Delaware","weight":5,"price":10}]

const carriers = Array.from(
  shippingMethodOptions.reduce((map, {carrier_token, carrier_name}) => {
    if (!map.has(carrier_token)) map.set(carrier_token, { carrier_token, carrier_name })
    return map
  }, new Map()).values()
)

console.log(carriers)
```

Comment: Be careful, you'll match `"fede" + "xFedex"`, etc

Comment: You could shorten your callback to `return map.has(key) ? map : map.set(key, obj)` as `set` returns the map

Comment: @Phil - Another good point, thanks. I find the `if` a little easier to read because then I don't have to remember what `.set()` returns. But on the other hand, using your suggestion means the curly brackets and `return` keyword can be dropped from the arrow function, at least from my second version that didn't have the `key` variable.

Comment: You don't actually need `reduce` here, just do `new Map(data.map(x => [x.token, {x.token, x.name}]`